# Numpy: Find from matrix based on one of the columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have Xy:

```
matrix([[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 3, 3, 3],
        [2, 4, 4, 4]])
```

How do I return all rows with first column == 1?

Answer should be:

```
matrix([[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: I would recommend not using `np.matrix`. It has a lot of weird incompatibilities and pretty much only exists to make it easier to teach people who would find `dot` too much to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `matrix` type should generally be avoided in favour of `numpy.array`. However, if you feel you **need** to use it then you can filter a matrix using [`numpy.compress`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html#numpy.compress).

When doing so, its important to flatten your filter ...

```
>>> numpy.compress((m[:,0] == 1).flat, m, axis=0)
matrix([[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Here, `m[:,0] == 1` returns a boolean matrix indicating which rows are considered acceptable.  `numpy.compress` will choose just those acceptable rows for us.